# Periodic orbit of linear DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $B = (0\ \  b, -b\ \  0)$ , find a periodic orbit for $\dot{x} = Bx$.

**My attempt:** We know that $x(t) = e^{Bt}$ is a solution to $\dot{x} = Bx$. But since $B = (0\ \  b, -b\ \  0)$, $e^{Bt} = [cos(bt) \ -sin(bt), \sin(bt)\ \cos(bt)]$. If we replace $t$ by $t+2\pi$, we see that the solution is exactly the same.

Can anyone please help with this problem?

Comment: So... you want to recognize the $(x,y)$-curve parametrized as $x=x_0\cos(bt)-y_0\sin(bt)$, $y(t)=x_0\sin(bt)+y_0\cos(bt)$. Can you solve the case $(x_0,y_0)=(1,0)$?

Comment: @Did: Yes. But what does it imply?? And where did you get that vector from? It's the basis for the 2nd column of $B$

Comment: Sorry but "Can you solve case blabla?" is euphemism for "Please solve trivial case blabla and show your solution in this case".

Comment: @Did: For $(x_0, y_0) = (1, 0)$, $x(t)= cos(bt)$, $y(t)= sin(bt)$. Now what does this imply sir?

Comment: Thus, what is the curve that the moving point $(x(t),y(t))$ stays on, in this case?

Comment: @Did: Circle centered at origin with radius 1. So $(cos(bt)\ \sin(bt))$ is a periodic orbit. Correct?

Comment: Yes. Now it only remains to extend this idea to other starting points $(x_0,y_0)$...

Comment: @Did: I got it! Since $x^{2}(t) + y^{2}(t) = (x_0)^2+(y_0)^2$, which is some constant, the periodic orbit is a circle centered at origin with radius $=$ RHS$^{0.5}$

Comment: This is correct. You might post it as an answer.

Comment: @Did: thanks a ton! It's quite simple, yet I'm dumb:(

Comment: @Evgeny: my apology, but can you help me with the last step of the 2nd part?

Comment: Why did you completely change the question once you received an answer to it in the comments? This is *annoying* and contrary to the way the site is supposed to function.

Comment: @Did: I thought I could solve part (b) by myself, but then realized I stumbled upon the last step. Can you stop worrying about those MINOR things? I did give you credits for your help in my post above. If you find it annoying, then my apology.

Comment: @Lutzl: can you help with this problem?

Comment: @Did: can you settle down our conflict? I need your help me with the new part, as nobody is interested in helping me solve for the last step of proving it as an eclipse:(

Comment: @Variable: can you give this problem a try?